# How to populate a scrapy.Field as a dictionary

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm building a scraper for [www.apkmirror.com](http://www.apkmirror.com/) using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) (with the [SitemapSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#sitemapspider) spider). So far the following works:

```
DEBUG = True

from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from apkmirror_scraper.items import ApkmirrorScraperItem


class ApkmirrorSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'apkmirror-spider'
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.apkmirror.com/sitemap_index.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [(r'.*-android-apk-download/$', 'parse')]

    if DEBUG:
        custom_settings = {'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 20}

    def parse(self, response):
        item = ApkmirrorScraperItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@title]/text()').extract_first()
        item['developer'] = response.xpath('//h3[@title]/a/text()').extract_first()
        return item
```

where the `ApkMirrorScraperItem` is defined in `items.py` as follows:

```
class ApkmirrorScraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    developer = scrapy.Field()
```

The resulting JSON output if I run it from the project directory using the command

```
scrapy crawl apkmirror-spider -o data.json
```

is an array of JSON dictionaries with keys `url`, `title`, and `developer`, and the corresponding strings as values. I would like to modify this, however, so that the value of `developer` is itself a dictionary with a `name` field, so that I can populate it like this:

```
item['developer']['name'] = response.xpath('//h3[@title]/a/text()').extract_first()
```

However, if I try this I get `KeyError`s, also if I initialize the `developer`'s `Field` (which is a `dict` according to https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#item-fields) as `developer = scrapy.Field(name=None)`. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrapy implements fields internally as dicts, but this does not mean they should be accessed as dicts. When you call `item['developer']`, what you are really doing is getting the **value** of the field, not the field itself. So, if the value has not been set yet, this will throw a KeyError.

Considering this, there are two ways you could go about your problem.

First one, just set the developer field value to a dict:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = ApkmirrorScraperItem()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@title]/text()').extract_first()
    item['developer'] = {'name': response.xpath('//h3[@title]/a/text()').extract_first()}
    return item
```

Second one, create a new Developer class and set the developer value to be an instance of this class:

```
# this can go to items.py
class Developer(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()

def parse(self, response):
    item = ApkmirrorScraperItem()
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@title]/text()').extract_first()

    dev = Developer()        
    dev['name'] = response.xpath('//h3[@title]/a/text()').extract_first()       
    item['developer'] = dev

    return item
```

Hope it helps :)